# Python Socket Timing out

Tags: python, sockets

I am attempting to open a socket to google on port 80 but for the life of me I can't figure out why this is timing out. If I don't set a timeout it just hangs indefinitely.

I don't think my companies firewall is blocking this request. I can navigate to google.com in the browser so there shouldn't be any hangups here.

```
import socket

HOST = '173.194.121.39'   
PORT = 80             

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.settimeout(20)


data = s.recv(1024)
print(data)
s.close()
```

Comment: Disregard my comment. It was useless :-)

Comment: Examine your browser's configuration to determine if you have an HTTP proxy established. If so, your PC probably doesn't have connectivity to Google.

Comment: It **really** looks like a proxy issue. Even if you companie does not block the website, the proxy require an authentication and a request to access to google.com. I wold say the same as @Robᵩ: check if you have a proxy authentication anywhere.

Comment: I don't see where you issued a 'GET'.  Why would you expect to receive anything?

Comment: @stark I am using a (very weakly modified) version of the Python Socket Documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
import socket

HOST = 'www.google.com'
PORT = 80

IP = socket.gethostbyname(HOST)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((IP, PORT))

message = b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"

s.sendall(message)

data = s.recv(1024)
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
s.close()
```

What was wrong with you code:
Your code was directly using the IP, i tried looking up for the IP by hostname using `socket.gethostbyname()`. (*i dont know why :P*)

You were expecting data to be returned without sending any. I used `s.sendall` method to send a HTTP request (since you're using python3, the data must be sent in bytes). Also decoded the data returned to print.

I hope, it will work for you too.